# Trim unreachable code from Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, il

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the number of classes in an assembly impact performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418108/how-does-the-number-of-classes-in-an-assembly-impact-performance)

I have a fairly large .Net assembly containing common controls and components.  This the VS project file is used in several different VS solutions.  Any given application may only require a small subset of the code within the common assembly.  Is there any way to customise the build for each application to exclude code which is not required in order to reduce the assembly size.  I have looked at ILMerge but can not tell if it is capable of merging then trimming unreachable IL?

Comment: Dotfuscator can do this, but it's very expensive. Not sure if the community edition can do it - I think not though. ILMerge won't help you, unfortunately. It sounds to me like your assembly is too large and it should be refactored into several smaller assemblies.

Comment: Unless you merge everything into a single EXE, this is not possible for various reasons. Even then, it will be hard. You will need 100% code coverage of all use cases and then you can that info to remove chucks of unneeded IL. IMO, not worth it. Rather refactor your libraries.

Comment: Frankly, unless I was targeting small frameworks like phones, silverlight, CF, etc - I wouldn't get excited about this at all